# What exactly is considered a garbage collection root and how are they found in the HotSpot JVM?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-hotspot

**Intro:**

At university one learns that typical garbage collection roots in Java (and similar languages) are **static variables** of loaded classes, **thread-local variables** of currently running threads, "external references" such as **JNI handles**, and GC-specifics such as **old-to-young pointers** during Minor GCs of a generational garbage collector. In theory, this does not sound that hard.

---

**Problem:**

I am reading the [HotSpot source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/de8045923ad2) and was interested in how these garbage collection roots are detected inside the VM, i.e., which methods are used *inside* the JVM source code to visit all roots.

---

**Investigation:**

I found various files (e.g., [`psMarkSweep.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/de8045923ad2/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/psMarkSweep.cpp)), belonging to various GC implementations, that contain very similar constructs.

Following is the method `PSMarkSweep::mark_sweep_phase1` method from [`psMarkSweep.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/de8045923ad2/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/psMarkSweep.cpp) that I think covers the strong roots:

```
ParallelScavengeHeap::ParStrongRootsScope psrs;    
Universe::oops_do(mark_and_push_closure());    
JNIHandles::oops_do(mark_and_push_closure());   // Global (strong) JNI handles    
CLDToOopClosure mark_and_push_from_cld(mark_and_push_closure());
MarkingCodeBlobClosure each_active_code_blob(mark_and_push_closure(), !CodeBlobToOopClosure::FixRelocations);    
Threads::oops_do(mark_and_push_closure(), &mark_and_push_from_cld, &each_active_code_blob);    
ObjectSynchronizer::oops_do(mark_and_push_closure());    
FlatProfiler::oops_do(mark_and_push_closure());    
Management::oops_do(mark_and_push_closure());    
JvmtiExport::oops_do(mark_and_push_closure());    
SystemDictionary::always_strong_oops_do(mark_and_push_closure());    
ClassLoaderDataGraph::always_strong_cld_do(follow_cld_closure());    
// Do not treat nmethods as strong roots for mark/sweep, since we can unload them. 
//CodeCache::scavenge_root_nmethods_do(CodeBlobToOopClosure(mark_and_push_closure()));
```

The following code from [`psScavenge.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/de8045923ad2/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/psScavenge.cpp) seems to add tasks for the different types of GC roots:

```
if (!old_gen->object_space()->is_empty()) {
  // There are only old-to-young pointers if there are objects
  // in the old gen.
  uint stripe_total = active_workers;
  for(uint i=0; i < stripe_total; i++) {
    q->enqueue(new OldToYoungRootsTask(old_gen, old_top, i, stripe_total));
  }
}

q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::universe));
q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::jni_handles));
// We scan the thread roots in parallel
Threads::create_thread_roots_tasks(q);
q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::object_synchronizer));
q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::flat_profiler));
q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::management));
q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::system_dictionary));
q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::class_loader_data));
q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::jvmti));
q->enqueue(new ScavengeRootsTask(ScavengeRootsTask::code_cache));
```

Looking at `ScavangeRootsTask`, we see familiar code similar to the code in `psMarkSweep`:

```
void ScavengeRootsTask::do_it(GCTaskManager* manager, uint which) {
  assert(Universe::heap()->is_gc_active(), "called outside gc");

  PSPromotionManager* pm = PSPromotionManager::gc_thread_promotion_manager(which);
  PSScavengeRootsClosure roots_closure(pm);
  PSPromoteRootsClosure  roots_to_old_closure(pm);

  switch (_root_type) {
    case universe:
      Universe::oops_do(&roots_closure);
      break;    
    case jni_handles:
      JNIHandles::oops_do(&roots_closure);
      break;    
    case threads:
    {
      ResourceMark rm;
      CLDClosure* cld_closure = NULL; // Not needed. All CLDs are already visited.
      Threads::oops_do(&roots_closure, cld_closure, NULL);
    }
    break;    
    case object_synchronizer:
      ObjectSynchronizer::oops_do(&roots_closure);
      break;    
    case flat_profiler:
      FlatProfiler::oops_do(&roots_closure);
      break;    
    case system_dictionary:
      SystemDictionary::oops_do(&roots_closure);
      break;    
    case class_loader_data:
    {
      PSScavengeKlassClosure klass_closure(pm);
      ClassLoaderDataGraph::oops_do(&roots_closure, &klass_closure, false);
    }
    break;    
    case management:
      Management::oops_do(&roots_closure);
      break;    
    case jvmti:
      JvmtiExport::oops_do(&roots_closure);
      break;
    case code_cache:
      {
        MarkingCodeBlobClosure each_scavengable_code_blob(&roots_to_old_closure, CodeBlobToOopClosure::FixRelocations);
        CodeCache::scavenge_root_nmethods_do(&each_scavengable_code_blob);
      }
      break;    
    default:
      fatal("Unknown root type");
  }    
  // Do the real work
  pm->drain_stacks(false);
}
```

---

**Insight:**

This lists of GC roots in the source code look quite a bit larger than what I initially wrote in my first sentence, so I try to list them below, with some comments:

- *Universe*: Okay, the universe. Mostly mirrors of certain classes.
- *JNI handles*: Also clear, handles created via JNI that keep objects alive.
- *Threads*: This one visits the thead-local roots. But here we see the first difference. `psMarkSweep.cpp` uses a CLDToOopClosure and does something with Code blobs, while `psScavange.cpp` does not. Afaik, CLD stands for *Class loader data*, but I don't know why it is used in one case, but not in another. The same accounts for code blobs.
- *Object Synchronizer*: Monitors used for synchronization.
- *Flat Profiler*: A profiler that is part of Hotspot, keeps alive its class loader.
- *Management*: Objects that are kept alive for certain management services, such as MemoryPoolMXBean etc.
- *JVMTI*: Keeps alive JVMTI breakpoints and objects allocated by JVMTI.
- *System Dictionary*: Keeps alive all classes that are loaded by the Java system classloader, and thus the objects referenced by the classes' static fields.
- *Class Loader Data Graph*: This one is a bit unclear to me. I think this are the class loaders that are not the Java system classloader, i.e., this covers classes (and their static fields) that have been loaded by different class loaders?
- *Code Cache*: The code cache contains certain code blobs, but I am still not sure what exactly these code blobs are. It seems a code blob represent information about (compiled) code frames, am I right about this? But I still do not understand why these code blobs are sometimes visited while traversing the thread stacks (as done in `psMarkSweep.cpp`) and sometimes visited using the CodeCache (as done in `psScavenge.cpp`).
- *(Only for Minor GC) Old-to-young roots*: Clear.

---

**Questions:**

While many things can be found in the source code, I still struggle to understand some of these GC roots, or how these GC roots are found.

- What is a code blob? What GC roots does it contain that are not already covered by visiting a thread with an oop closure? What is the code cache?
- To gather all thread-local roots: What is the difference between using a `CLDToOopClosure` and a `MarkingCodeBlobClosure` in combination with `Threads::oops_do` (as done in `psMarkSweep.cpp`), compared to visiting the threads with an oop closure and additionally executing `ClassLoaderDataGraph::oops_do` and `CodeCache::scavenge_root_nmethods_do` (as used by `psScavenge.cpp`).
- What is the class loader data graph (compared to the system dictionary)? Is it the collection of the applications class loaders?
- What about interned strings, how do they survive GCs? Do they reside somewhere outside the heap, where garbage collection does not affect them?
- Do other garbage collectors, e.g., the G1 GC, introduce new types of root pointers? (I don't think that this should be the case)

---

**Remark:**

I know this is a veeeery long question with various subquestions, but I think it would have been hard to split it into multiple ones.
I appreciate every posted answer, even if it does not cover an answer to all the questions asked above, even answers to parts of them will help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've already discovered yourself, `<Subsystem>::oops_do()` is a typical mechanism in HotSpot JVM to visit GC roots of `<Subsystem>`. Good analysis, by the way. Just keep going through VM sources, and you'll find the answers, as there are plenty useful comments in the code.

Note that the purpose of `oops_do` is not only to mark reachable objects, but also to process the references themselves, particularly, to *relocate* them during compaction.

---

CodeBlob is a piece of generated code. It covers not only JITted methods (aka `nmethods`) but also various VM stubs and routines generated in runtime.

```
// CodeBlob - superclass for all entries in the CodeCache.
//
// Suptypes are:
//   nmethod            : Compiled Java methods (include method that calls to native code)
//   RuntimeStub        : Call to VM runtime methods
//   DeoptimizationBlob : Used for deoptimizatation
//   ExceptionBlob      : Used for stack unrolling
//   SafepointBlob      : Used to handle illegal instruction exceptions
```

These pieces of code may contain embedded references to Heap objects, e.g. String/Class/MethodHandle literals and static final constants.

---

The purpose of `CLDToOopClosure` in `Threads::oops_do` is to mark objects referenced through method pointers not marked otherwise:

```
// The method pointer in the frame might be the only path to the method's
// klass, and the klass needs to be kept alive while executing. The GCs
// don't trace through method pointers, so typically in similar situations
// the mirror or the class loader of the klass are installed as a GC root.
// To minimze the overhead of doing that here, we ask the GC to pass down a
// closure that knows how to keep klasses alive given a ClassLoaderData.
cld_f->do_cld(m->method_holder()->class_loader_data());
```

Similarly, `MarkingCodeBlobClosure` is used to mark objects referenced only from *active* nmethods:

```
// In cases where perm gen is collected, GC will want to mark
// oops referenced from nmethods active on thread stacks so as to
// prevent them from being collected. However, this visit should be
// restricted to certain phases of the collection only. The
// closure decides how it wants nmethods to be traced.
if (cf != NULL)
  cf->do_code_blob(_cb);
```

Note that `CodeCache::scavenge_root_nmethods_do` is not called during marking phase:

```
// Do not treat nmethods as strong roots for mark/sweep, since we can unload them.
//CodeCache::scavenge_root_nmethods_do(CodeBlobToOopClosure(&mark_and_push_closure));
```

---

`SystemDictionary` is responsible mainly for resolving symbolic names of classes. It does not serve as a GC root for marking (except for Bootstrap and System classloaders). On the other hand, `ClassLoaderDataGraph` maintains the complete linkset of class loader entities. It *does* serve as GC root and is responsible for class unloading.

```
// A ClassLoaderData identifies the full set of class types that a class
// loader's name resolution strategy produces for a given configuration of the
// class loader.
// Class types in the ClassLoaderData may be defined by from class file binaries
// provided by the class loader, or from other class loader it interacts with
// according to its name resolution strategy.
// ...
// ClassLoaderData carries information related to a linkset (e.g.,
// metaspace holding its klass definitions).
// The System Dictionary and related data structures (e.g., placeholder table,
// loader constraints table) as well as the runtime representation of classes
// only reference ClassLoaderData.
//
// Instances of java.lang.ClassLoader holds a pointer to a ClassLoaderData that
// that represent the loader's "linking domain" in the JVM.
```

---

Interned strings *don't need* to survive GC. They are not GC roots. It's OK to unload interned strings unreachable otherwise, and HotSpot actually does that.

---

A Garbage Collector does not introduce new types of roots itself, but it may use algorithms and data structures that affect the meaning of "reachability". E.g. concurrent collectors may treat all references modified between initial mark and final remark as reachable even if they are not.

Answer (score 1):

As the this post has several questions, I dare to answer a few of them:

1) A code blob is JITed code. It may contain hardcoded (as assembler immediate) object pointers (for example to class objects, or to static finals). If the object is moved, the immediate in the code is adjusted.

2) no idea

3) classloader data are native meta data objects (not within the heap) that may contain references (for example) to loaded classes.

4) interned strings reside in the heap just as regular objects (in old VMs in the perm gen). The only difference is that (for the reason of interning and caching) they are usually never collected and always implicitly alive.
5) To the best of my knowledge, a GC itself should not introduce a new category of GC roots, after all, a GC root as a concept that is GC-independent. However, each GC might store and handle them differently.

EDIT:

Just thought about something else:

2) the VM makes heavy use of closures, which basically means virtual calls. Virtual calls may be expensive however (especially when u do them often, for example for every object and every pointer in the heap), so instead of combining existing closures, the VM often implements specialized closures to avoid unnecessary virtual calls. This may be a reason for it.

1') i just noticed that one might interpret my answer as it being just redundant roots (because class objects and static finals are always referenced from somewhere else too). First, they are not redundant from a GC perspective because the immediates must still be adjusted if the object is moved. And second, the JIT may decide to hardcode the pointer to ANY object, if it for example detects that while interpreting, a specific call ALWAYS returns a pointer to the same object. So a code blob root may be the only root for a specific object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding interned strings: "..they are usually never collected and always implicitly alive.": -> I also thought this, but I don't see any code in the snippets posted above that reflects this. I know there is a StringTable class in the HotSpot JVM, but it is not used to detect roots as far as I can see...